# Is this process for finding if this correlation is statistically significant correct?

Tags: statistics, correlation

Let's suppose I have calculated the correlation between stock prices and P/E ratios from each quarter from 2010 to 2015 (a total of 24 quarters) to be 0.85.  Assuming a 5% significance level, I want to know if this correlation is statistically significant.

My process went like this:
24 periods means I have 22 degrees of freedom. My null hypothesis is that the correlation between all stock prices and P/E ratios for this stock is 0.  My alternative hypothesis is that it is not 0.  Therefore I believe this is called a "two-tailed test."  Since this is a two-tailed test, the critical value is 2.074.

Now I can use the test statistic
$t = \frac{r\sqrt{n - 2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$

where $r$ is the correlation coefficient and $n - 2$ is the degrees of freedom. Plugging in the values aboe, I get that
$t = \frac{0.85\sqrt{22}}{\sqrt{1-(0.85)^2}}$.  This equals $7.568$, which is greater than my critical value of $2.074$.
Therefore this correlation is statistically significant.

Is my process correct?

Comment: Didn't check arithmetic, but the idea is fine for normal data.